# Inline image embedding without gmail?

Tags: email, gmail, inline, embedding

Can you embed inline images in email that is not gmail? i found this but i think it is for gmail only?

[HTML Email in Gmail - embedding images](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7292760/html-email-in-gmail-embedding-images/13256105#13256105)

Answer (score 3):

http://email.about.com/od/windowslivehotmailtips/qt/et_inline_image.htm
There is a blog post explain this in detail, I actually think most email services support inline image embedding

Comment: actually i found the solution and it works pretty sweet: you need 2 things 1. the code explained here http://www.bigfastblog.com/embed-base64-encoded-images-inline-in-html and 2. an encoded image which you can make here http://www.motobit.com/util/base64-decoder-encoder.asp