# HTML Email Linked Resource Image Only shows in reply

Tags: image, debugging, html-email, reply, outlook.com

Odd one here.

I am embedding an image in an email using a linked resource. It doesn't show in the original generated email but when I click on reply or forward it shows up fine.

The following happens with Outlook.com (Hotmail) and Chrome/Firefox:

- It doesn't show in either the default view or reply view in IE
- It shows the image in the original and the reply on my iPad native email client
- It shows same as Chrome/Firefox in Opera on the iPad.

Anyone know how to fix this anomaly?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Use a multipart email to embed the image in the email:

- [How to create an email with embedded images that is compatible with the most mail clients](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4018709/)
- [Key Concepts of MHTML](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/exchange/ms988645)