# How to send html in email with image(base 64 string ) to Outlook, gmail etc

Tags: c#, html

I have create html with image(base 64 string )  for sending mail.
But on Outlook it doesnt show image and not support html.

what to do, Please help me.

thanks
Kamlesh

Answer (score 0):

This may be the answer you're looking for - [How to create an email with embedded images that is compatible with the most mail clients](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4018709/how-to-create-an-email-with-embedded-images-that-is-compatible-with-the-most-mai)

Note that images are embedded using `<img src="cid:....">`